# Flask-LDAP3-Login Filter issue - User cannot login

Tags: flask, active-directory, python-3.6, ldap3

Using flask-ldap3-login to query AD for my web app logins. Works for everyone; but, for users who have "()" in their First name in AD. Here's the Debug log.

UN-SUCCESSFULL LOGIN

`DEBUG:root:Validating LDAPLoginForm against LDAP`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Opening connection with bind user 'mybinduser@mydomain.com'`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Successfully bound to LDAP as 'mybinduser@mydomain.com' for search_bind method`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Performing an LDAP Search using filter '(&(objectclass=person)(sAMAccountName=ebadu))', base 'DC=mydomain,DC=com', and scope 'SUBTREE'`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Opening connection with bind user 'CN=Badu\, Ericka (EB),OU=HELPDESK,DC=mydomain,DC=com'`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Directly binding a connection to a server with user:'CN=Badu\, ericka (EB),OU=HELPDESK,DC=mydomain,DC=com'`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Authentication was successful for user 'ebadu'`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Searching for groups for specific user with filter '(&(objectclass=group)(uniqueMember=CN=Badu\, Ericka (EB),OU=HELPDESK,DC=mydomain,DC=com))' , base 'DC=mydomain,DC=com' and scope 'LEVEL'`
`ERROR:flask_ldap3_login:malformed filter`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Destroying connection at <0x7f8629604c50>`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Destroying connection at <0x7f8628eabf98>`

SUCCESFULL LOGIN

`DEBUG:root:Validating LDAPLoginForm against LDAP`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Opening connection with bind user 'mybinduser@mydomain.com'`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Successfully bound to LDAP as 'mybinduser@mydomain.com' for search_bind method`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Performing an LDAP Search using filter '(&(objectclass=person)(sAMAccountName=mpeters))', base 'DC=mydomain,DC=com', and scope 'SUBTREE'`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Opening connection with bind user 'CN=Peters\, Mike,OU=HELPDESK,DC=mydomain,DC=com'`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Directly binding a connection to a server with user:'CN=Peters\, Mike,OU=HELPDESK,DC=mydomain,DC=com'`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Authentication was successful for user 'mpeters'`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Searching for groups for specific user with filter '(&(objectclass=group)(uniqueMember=CN=Peters\, Mike,OU=HELPDESK,DC=mydomain,DC=com))' , base 'DC=mydomain,DC=com' and scope 'LEVEL'`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Destroying connection at <0x7f8629683828>`
`DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Destroying connection at <0x7f8628e91048>`

The AD logs says "An account was successfully logged on"; however, the user does not log in to the app. The user has no issues login in with the AD credentials anywhere else.

What might be the issue?

This is the flask-ldap3-login code:

```
LDAP_USER_RDN_ATTR = 'cn'
LDAP_USER_LOGIN_ATTR = 'sAMAccountName'
LDAP_BASE_DN = 'DC=mydomain,DC=com'
LDAP_REQUIRED_GROUP = 'ou=helpdesk,dc=mydomain,dc=com'
LDAP_USER_SEARCH_SCOPE = 'SUBTREE'
```

Comment: Any odd characters in that person's username or display name, or anywhere on the account? (comma, slash, parenthesis, etc.)

Comment: @GabrielLuci Thank you for asking! I am going over the account and comparing it to another one. I see lots of weird characters in the 'userParameters' attribute in the problem user's account. I am trying to find another user who has that attribute to see if I can replicate the login issue. I will respond, hopefully soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! Seems to be solved in the latest version of flask-ldap3-login. I did not upgrade but modified existing code:

Replaced this:

```
    `search_filter = '(&{group_filter}({members_attr}={user_dn}))'.format('`    
    `group_filter=self.config.get('LDAP_GROUP_OBJECT_FILTER'),`    
    `members_attr=self.config.get('LDAP_GROUP_MEMBERS_ATTR'),`  
    `user_dn=dn`
```

with this:

```
    `safe_dn = ldap3.utils.conv.escape_filter_chars(dn)`  
    `search_filter = '(&{group_filter}({members_attr}={user_dn}))'.format(`  
    `group_filter=self.config.get('LDAP_GROUP_OBJECT_FILTER'),`  
    `members_attr=self.config.get('LDAP_GROUP_MEMBERS_ATTR'),`  
    `user_dn=safe_dn`
```

Answer (score 0):

But "malformed filter" usually means that the LDAP query sent to AD isn't valid somehow. I asked about odd characters on the account, since if some special characters are not encoded properly, they can be misinterpreted as special characters used in LDAP queries.

It could be a bug in your code, or a bug in flask-ldap3-login. If you show your code, I *might* be able to give you some pointers.

Also, see if you can enable debug logging. It may tell you what the actual filter is that made it bomb. I'm not familiar with flask-ldap3-login, but, looking at the documentation, this might do it?:

```
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
```

Comment: There is ` (RH)' in the dn of the user, indeed. I queried AD and found no one else that's allowed to login to the web app, with that in their dn. The user is just putting in their samAccountName and password in the app login form. AD logs says "An account was successfully logged on". It's when the user's attributes come back to the app, that the dn of this user comes with the special characters and the error is raised, I believe. Debug did not add anything new - Same error. Going to try to create a test user to try to replicate.Thoughts?

Comment: Parenthesis are special characters in LDAP queries, but matching parenthesis should be ok. I have seen problems when there is only one (opening, but not closing). Is that the only special character in the DN?

Comment: I was going to suggest you open an issue with them in GitHub, but I see you already did :)

Comment: Also, can you edit your question and show your code where the error happens?

Comment: I have updated the question, Gabriel. Let me know if the edits help.

Comment: Does the username (`sAmAccountName`) have any special characters?

Comment: And are those the only configuration settings that you're setting (those `LDAP_` settings)?

Comment: samaccount name does not have special characters. I mispoke. It's the First name of the user that has the (RH). So, it's, say "Gabriel (GL)", for example. So, the CN is what's used by Flask-Login as the current_user.

Comment: I was trying to look through their source code. I believe your authentication would go through the [`authenticate_search_bind`](https://github.com/nickw444/flask-ldap3-login/blob/master/flask_ldap3_login/__init__.py#L412) function. It does also search for groups if the `LDAP_SEARCH_FOR_GROUPS` config property is `True` (which it is by default). You can try setting that to `False`, and see if it works. If it does, you know it's the group search that is failing. It'll get us closer anyway.

Comment: Their code makes a lot of calls to `log.debug()`. It would be nice to know where that's going. Seems like it would be helpful.

Comment: I appreciate your ongoing assistance. I was able to reproduce the issue by creating an AD user with similar first name "Victor (VT)". How could I make flask-login play nice with special characters in the CN of a user?

Comment: So it's in both the firstName and cn attributes? I'm not entirely sure right now. Add this to your GitHub issue. Maybe they'll respond. Or maybe they can tell you how to enable debug logging.